# react native How to go back to previous page if back button is pressed in WebView?

Tags: react-native

I am opening a url in react native web view , my problem is that when a user navigates between links of the page and clicks go back button of the phone , the app exit , I hope that you could help me to find a way that user when click go back , the app goes to the previous page not exiting , that's how I am calling the url in web view

```
   <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
```

[image]

Comment: It isn't `react-navigation` bug. You can refer the way handle hardware back button in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html#handling-the-hardware-back-button-in-android

Comment: have you find any solution